# Django saving datetime based on per object timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

For the majority of my application saving datetimes with the TIME_ZONE and USE_TZ settings are fine. My question is, how can I accomplish saving a model with a datetime that is in UTC, but the datetime is set so that converting back to the users inputted timezone is correct? Model, view, form and html given below. This code will work if USE_TZ = False in the settings.py file, but I would like to keep the timezone for everything else in the project.

Model:

```
class TZTestModel(models.Model):
    timezone = TimeZoneField()
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

View:

```
class TZTestView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "tz_test.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            'form': self.form
        }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form = TZTestForm(self.request.POST or None)
        return super(TZTestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.form.save()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Form:

```
class TZTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TZTestModel

    def clean(self):
        timezone = self.cleaned_data['timezone']
        dt = self.cleaned_data['dt']
        dt = timezone.localize(dt)
        self.cleaned_data['dt'] = pytz.UTC.normalize(dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example:

I would like to be able to enter a timezone of 'US/Alaska' and a datetime of today at 13:00, save that as it's UTC value, then be able to convert back to 'US/Alaska' and get the correct value.

Essentially I am trying to save one model's datetime in a different timezone than my application, where the timezone is specified by the user in the same form that the datetime is specified in.

Comment: Have you looked into [time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#)?

Comment: kroolik, yes I have looked into time zones and am using them. For instance in my settings.py file I have my TIME_ZONE set to use 'Pacific/Honolulu' and all dates saved as UTC work fine.


My problem is not in displaying timezone information it is saving an object's datetime with a user specified timezone that is different from my servers.

I would like django to save an object's datetime with a timezone specified on the same model. I can replace the tzinfo with the timezone I want, but this leads to incorrect results due to DST not being calculated before the save.

Comment: Wouldn't keeping user's timezone in the session be sufficient? Or you need more granular way of selecting the timezone?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with the users timezone. This is computing a datetime on a model, where the model also contains a timezone. The datetime needs to be computed independently from the user or django's timezone setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue with object-level timezones.

I found [this blog entry](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/01/09/managing-events-explicit-time-zones/). It's not perfect but **it works!** and is not too complex. Plus handling the Admin is dealt with.

Pasting the snippets here:

#### Making sure the form is processed in the wanted timezone:

```
def view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        tz_form = TimeZoneForm(request.POST)
        if tz_form.is_valid():
            tz = tz_form.cleaned_data['event_time_zone']
            timezone.activate(tz)
            # Process the full form now
    else:
        # assuming we have an event object already
        timezone.activate(event.event_time_zone)
        # Continue to create form for display on the web page
```

#### Displaying correctly in the Admin list view

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'event_datetime_in_timezone', ...]

    def event_datetime_in_timezone(self, event):
        """Display each event time on the changelist in its own timezone"""
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
        dt = event.event_datetime.astimezone(pytz_timezone(event.event_time_zone))
        return dt.strftime(fmt)
    event_datetime_in_timezone.short_description = _('Event time')
```

#### Interpret correctly the datetimne in Admin Add view

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...

    # Override add view so we can peek at the timezone they've entered and
    # set the current time zone accordingly before the form is processed
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            tz_form = TimeZoneForm(request.POST)
            if tz_form.is_valid():
                timezone.activate(tz_form.cleaned_data['event_time_zone'])
        return super(EventAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

#### Handling correctly timezones in the Admin edit view

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...

    # Override change view so we can peek at the timezone they've entered and
    # set the current time zone accordingly before the form is processed
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            tz_form = TimeZoneForm(request.POST)
            if tz_form.is_valid():
                timezone.activate(tz_form.cleaned_data['event_time_zone'])
        else:
            obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id))
            timezone.activate(obj.event_time_zone)
        return super(EventAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: pastebin source for form field: http://pastebin.com/j4TnnHTS
further discussion: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21300

It appears that the way to do this is to create a custom form field that returns a naive datetime, then convert that to the timezone the user specifies, then convert that to UTC.

Custom field:

```
class DateTimeNoTimeZoneField(forms.DateTimeField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        """
        Validates that the input can be converted to a datetime. Returns a
        Python datetime.datetime object.
        """
        if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            return datetime.datetime(value.year, value.month, value.day)
        if isinstance(value, list):
            # Input comes from a SplitDateTimeWidget, for example. So, it's two
            # components: date and time.
            if len(value) != 2:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
            if value[0] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES and value[1] in validators.EMPTY_VALUES:
                return None
            value = '%s %s' % tuple(value)
                # Try to coerce the value to unicode.
        unicode_value = force_text(value, strings_only=True)
        if isinstance(unicode_value, six.text_type):
            value = unicode_value.strip()
        # If unicode, try to strptime against each input format.
        if isinstance(value, six.text_type):
            for format in self.input_formats:
                try:
                    return self.strptime(value, format)
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    continue
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
```

Form:

```
class TZTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dt = DateTimeNoTimeZoneField()

    class Meta:
        model = TZTestModel

    def clean(self):
        tz = self.cleaned_data['timezone']
        dt = self.cleaned_data['dt']
        dt = pytz.UTC.normalize(tz.localize(dt).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
        self.cleaned_data['dt'] = dt
        return self.cleaned_data
```