# Django datetime field not updating using time zone

Tags: python, django, python-datetime, django-timezone

```
setings.py:-
    USE_TZ = True
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

class MyModel(models.Model):

        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        # time zone related field
        user_time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        time_difference = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        client_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        display_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

MyModel object create

MyModel.objects.create(user_time_zone=form.cleaned_data['prefer_time_zone'])


Signal called after the MyModel is created

def update_time_zone(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:

        fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"

        now_utc = instance.created_at

        if instance.user_time_zone:

            if instance.user_time_zone == 'US/Alaska':

                alaska = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('US/Alaska'))
                print "alaska is_aware", is_aware(alaska)
                print "alaska is_naive", is_naive(alaska)

                instance.client_date = alaska
                instance.display_date = alaska
                instance.time_difference = alaska.strftime(fmt).split(" ")[2]
                instance.save()

                print "alaska now utc", type(now_utc)
                print "alaska type", type(alaska)

                print "alaska", alaska

                # At here i got updated value but when i see inside
                # postgres database value is not updated 

                print "instance.client_date", instance.client_date
                print "us/alaska", alaska.strftime(fmt)

signals.post_save.connect(update_time_zone, sender=MyModel)


instance.created_at = 2016-02-06 21:42:22.552000+00:00
alaska = 2016-02-06 12:42:22.552000-09:00
```

Issue:-

After converting instance.created_at to 'US/Alaska' output is 2016-02-06 12:42:22.552000-09:00. But when I make client_date and display_date equal to alaska like in above signal, it not saved my newly updated alaska value rather then it update client_date and display_date by instance.created_at value by adding 5 hours. I need to update the client_date and display_date by alaska time zone.

When I calling instance.save() it has no effect in postgres database. Whats the issue? Why it not updating the alaska value? is there any thing like django force not to update the new value instead update the value using default time zone?

Comment: checked these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505640/django-saving-datetime-based-on-per-object-timezone and  http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/

Comment: Yes I am following the saltycrane blog. But client_date and display_date is not updating my alaska time zone. Even I have converted, it has no effect inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

timezone-aware datetime objects `.. 00:00:00+00:00` and `.. 01:00:00+01:00` correspond to exactly **the same** time moment. They are only displayed differently. In Django, [*a datetime represents **a point in time**. It’s absolute: it doesn’t depend on anything.*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#database)

`dt = dt.astimezone(whatever_tz)` has no effect on the value in the database. [The database connection’s time zone is set to UTC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#database) (`USE_TZ=True`). If you need to preserve `client_date`'s timezone info; store it separately.